# MLA bibliography style in computer science

Tags: citations, computer-science, citation-style, bibtex, electrical-engineering

Does anyone know a computer science or engineering journal that uses MLA as their bibliography style?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? You're not going to choose a journal on the basis of their bibliography style, are you?

Comment: :-) Our thesis office requires us to follow the biobliography style of a journal in our field.  I like MLA but can't seem to find a jurnal with MLA style.

Comment: You may want to look at digital humanities journals. If any are going to use MLA, it'll be them. (And hopefully whatever journal that be they outright reject MLA 8th ed. and its utter nonsense).